# Changing console color not working exactly in multithreaded applications

Tags: c#, console, thread-safety

I am working on multithreaded application(a server) which is basically a console application. In which I show processing log to console which is by default in white color.
but on successful transaction I show the text in green and on unsuccessful transaction I show text in red. So I have three separate function in Program.cs for this.

For simple log

```
public static void Write(string text)
{
        try
        {
            Console.Out.Write(text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
```

For unsuccessful transaction I change color to red, then print and then back to white

```
    public static void WriteError(string text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + text);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
```

For successful Transaction I change color to green, then print and then back to white

```
    public static void WriteSuccess(string text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + text);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    }
```

The problem is when more than 200 clients connected and the log of transactions of each client is printing on console. And when I change color like green for single line it cause many other lines of normal log to green as well. 
So please tell me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: I think you might need to lock

Answer (score 23):

If your class is the only one that is writing to the console, then locking on a single private object, as others mentioned, will work.

But if there are other writers, you will also need to synchronize with them, otherwise they could write while you're inside the lock. If you look at the implementation of `Console`, you will notice that `Console.Out` is a [`SyncTextWriter`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,9e3dd0323cf4ee8b), which synchronizes on itself (using `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`). This means that if you use that as your synchronization object, you will be synchronized with other writers:

```
lock (Console.Out)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + text);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
```

This will still not work correctly if the other writers also set colors and use their own synchronization object. But it will work if the other writers also synchronize on `Console.Out`.

The problem with this approach is that it relies on implementation details, but I'm not aware of any better solution.

Comment: I was trying to illustrate threads working by setting different colors to them in the Console output. However i don't fully understand how the colors got mixed up between the threads while your suggestion prevents this. Clearly the threads are not crossing eachother as the expected output value are printed out and it's corresponding thread name. However my initial thought (judjing by color mixeup) was that they did.

Answer (score 12):

There is your problem:

```
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + text);
```

You set the color, another thread interrupts, sets the color to something else and then you print the text (in the wrong color).

You need to protect the section with a lock:

```
 static object lockObj = new object();

 public static void WriteError(string text)
 {
    lock(lockObj)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + text);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
 }
```

The same thing you have to do for `WriteSuccess(...)`

Comment: is it a good idea to let the threads be able to write directly in the console?

Comment: which object it will be that I have to lock?

Comment: its not working. I have used your suggestion and used                static object lockObj = new object();

Comment: `WriteLine` can be thread safe, but `ForegroundColor` plus `WriteLine` plus `ForegroundColor` aren't. You can't ensure that no other thread is going to be selected by the OS scheduler before this three methods finish.

Comment: @MNaeemAshraf: You have to use the SAME lock for ALL methods where you set the color and the write something

Comment: Exactly. Where and how are you declaring the variable? It have to be a class variable (shared by all the objects of this class), not an instance variable (ie, na independient variable for each object of the class).

Comment: yes I have only two functions in which I change the color which are in same class. I declared lockObj in that class and locked that object in two functions where I am changing the color. but still the problem is not resolved.

Comment: @adirpanico I declated that object in Program.cs. Where I have these two functions

Comment: [Here](http://snipt.org/), for example. Just paste your code there, and copy/paste the page URL here.

Comment: I have a program.cs class its data member is private static Object _lockObj = new Object(); and it has three function that I have showed above other than Main. There is a class ApplicationController.cs that is accessed by each thread as a new object of ApplicationController.I call Program.Write(msg), Program.WriteSuccess(msg) and Program.WriteError(msg). I modified the code like   lock (_lockObj)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + text);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }

Comment: Mmmmm, maybe your problem here is that your three functions are exactly that: functions (shared methods of the class, instead instance methods). It means that you don't need to declare an object of the class Program to use this three functions, but I don't know exactly if this allow you to access from this functions to the class variables. Try declaring your _lockObj variable as public instead as private and tell us.

Comment: yes I have locked the WriteSuccess(...) as well. Here is the Link http://snipt.org/yahje0

Answer (score 1):

Make your colored writes atomic by using a lock statement:

```
// Only one thread can enter this section at a time
lock(_lockObj) 
{
   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
   Console.WriteLine("\t" + text);
   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
```

_lockObj should be declared as a private static member of your class:

```
private static Object _lockObj = new Object();
```

Comment: this is exactly the suggestion by @pivotnig

Comment: From the code you supplied, you need your Write method to  implement the locking as well, otherwise it will compete with the other two methods which change the color:
        public static void Write(string text)
        {
                lock(_lockObj)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You should synchronize access to the console using a Mutex or a monitor (`lock` on some object would be easier).